# Match all strings in a dictionary-style file of desired length

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I have a list of words, all separated by new lines:

```
tomato
cucumber
potato
onion
apples
banana
bread
butter
bacon
salsa
chips
```

I want to output all words which have a desired string length *n*. If *n* = 5, the output words should be:

```
chips
salsa
bacon
bread
onion
```

I know that `sed 's/""//g' list.txt | awk '{ print length }'` will output the length of each line, and I can match on those that equal 5, but want the content of those particular lines.

Comment: What have you done that does not work? We will not write the program for you and you are expected to show a minimum of effort. We will gladly help you figure out what is not working in your code.

Comment: A bit tongue in cheek... `cat list.txt | awk '{ print length($1), $1 }' | sort -k1,1n | awk '$1 == 5' | cut -f2`. Or just `awk 'length($1) == 5' list.txt`... I have no idea what your `sed 's/""//g'` bit is supposed to be accomplishing there, as there are no double quotes in the input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -E`:

```
grep -E '^.{5}$' file
onion
bread
bacon
salsa
chips
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} NF==5' file
onion
bread
bacon
salsa
chips
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -n '/^.....$/p' file
onion
bread
bacon
salsa
chips
```

Or:

```
sed -n '/^.\{5\}$/p' file
```

#### Using Python

```
$ python -c $'for line in open("file"):\n   if len(line)==6: print(line.rstrip())'
onion
bread
bacon
salsa
chips
```